# Kafka cluster verification

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a problem now that `Kafka` data is piled up, but only one machine is like this, now my problem is that there is no `kafka client` on the server I am on, and I don't know the `zookeeper` address, how can I verify the cluster is normal?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Kafka client installed to communicate with the cluster, so install one.

E.g On Ubuntu

```
apt-get install -y kcat
kcat -L -b kafka-address:9092  # check cluster connectivity
```

You don't need Zookeeper, and it wouldn't show anything useful

Alternatively, tell your Kafka administrator to setup monitoring tools so you don't need to install/run random CLI tools / scripts.

Comment: Can ```kafka-console-consumer.sh``` And ```kafka-console-producer.sh``` be implemented?

Comment: They are installed as part of Kafka itself, and not separately downloadables, if that's what you mean. `kcat` includes functionality for both producing and consuming, though, and doesn't require a Java installation, so those aren't necessary